# How to Set Text Position in TextView with Compound Drawables?

Tags: android

I have a textview.I have set setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds of textview.After that when I set text to the textfield the text shifted to right.How can I bring the text to the middle.Please help me.

Thanks for help in advance.

```
Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(resizedbitmap);   
description.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d,null,null,null);
description.setText("hello");
description.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
description.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: can you show us the exact code snippet where you are having difficulties.

Comment: Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(resizedbitmap);
description.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d,null,null,null);                                            description.setText("hello");  
    description.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
description.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Comment: So you are placing a Drawable (d) to the left of the text. Shouldn't that move your text to the right?

Comment: I want to set background image of textview and set some text to the textview.I expect text to appear above the image but text is apearing on the right of image.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have done that.I need to replace setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds from setBackgroundDrawable.

Comment: That would indeed do the trick. For future people searching you should answer your own question (it may be a while before you can mark it as accepted). That way there is an answer listed for the question.